# JSF, primefaces and websphere can't find the enter page

Tags: jsf, primefaces, websphere

I use JSF, Primefaces and websphere.

I made a web project in maven with two maven modules.

But when i start the websphere server and the url appears and i click on it, does the webbrowser show that he doesn't find the page.

Is there something wrong in my web.xml?

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" version="3.0">
    <display-name>Tinnenhoek-BackOffice</display-name>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <async-supported>false</async-supported>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>
        /faces/*.xhtml</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

The page that should be seen is main.xhtml

Comment: What is the url you are using? Are you deploying to a remote web server or local/IDE? I can't tell from your question

Comment: Have you defined a welcome-file?